# Can't constraint to layoutMarginGuides in iOS 10

Tags: autolayout, ios11, nslayoutconstraint

I'm attempting to constrain my view to the layoutMarginGuide's .bottom attribute.

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([NSLayoutConstraint(item: someLabel, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view.layoutMarginsGuide, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)])
```

I'm doing this in viewDidLoad() after setting the layoutMargins of my view as such:

```
view.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 12, right: 0)
```

When running on an iOS 11 device it works fine but on iOS 10 devices my label is flush with the bottom of the view. Any ideas?

Side note: I'm setting "insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea" to false on iOS 11, but I don't think that has any bearing on the bug I'm seeing.